# Vector class sort not working

Tags: java

I created this vector;

```
    Vector<Integer> list =  new Vector<>();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(20);
    list.add(30);
    list.add(40);
    list.add(50);
```

I try to sort it as follows:

```
 list.sort();
```

But inside brackets of sort method I get this error:

> sort(Comparator) in Vector cannot be applied to ();

What parameters do I have to put inside brackets of sort method to make sort work.

Comment: As the compiler error suggests, you need to provide a `Comparator`.

Comment: There is no empty `List::sort` method. You always have to provide a `Comparator`. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-)

Comment: Otherwise do `Collections.sort(list);`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Java API Specification for the Vector class, it implements the List interface which is needed to use the `Collections.sort` method:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

it will sort vector elements in ascending order by default

if you want to sort them in descending order you can use comparator:

```
Comparator comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();

Collections.sort(list,comparator);
```

Comment: Collections.sort will only work if the Collection elements extend Comparable themself. The code in the question uses a raw vector and seems to add Integers, so he might get lucky and have it work.